# Using Do Loop and Variables to stack columns

Tags: vba, ms-access

Updated with code below:

I'm thinking this might be very quick for someone who is familiar with using a do loop an variables. I have a table with a lot of columns, what I need to do is stack the columns in sets of three (I would do this with a union but there are just way too many columns).

For example the columns are currently in linear form, I would want to stack their data:

Example:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 etc.

To

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

I have never worked with a do loop in access and I think I would need to do that and combine with a variable where I append columns 1, 2, 3 to a table, then append columns  4, 5, 6 to the same table etc.

I have always had trouble getting my head around how to use the variables in VBA but I will continue to see if I can figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Working code below that I came up with, not sure if it is the best way to do it:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()


Dim int1 As Integer
Dim int2 As Integer
Dim int3 As Integer
int1 = 1
int2 = 2
int3 = 3

DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningsoff)


Do Until int1 = CurrentDb.TableDefs("Data").Fields.Count + 1

DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Stack ( 1, 2, 3 ) SELECT Data.T" & CStr(int1) & ", Data.T" & CStr(int2) & ", Data.T" & CStr(int3) & " FROM Data")

int1 = int1 + 3
int2 = int2 + 3
int3 = int3 + 3

Loop
DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningson)

MsgBox CurrentDb.TableDefs("Data").Fields.Count + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you want to "stack their data" ? Split it into x number of records ? Combine all the data in a single record in multiple fields.. ? This is a very weird question. Can you give more detail of what you are trying to do ? It seems you might be doing things wrong in the first place.

Comment: The data needs to be in 3 columns: ID, Date and Hours. I receive a cross tab spreadsheet (25,000 rows by 156 columns) which I need to break out into those three columns, something like 3.4 million rows long. 

Right now I am using an excel macro to turn it from cross tab into sets of three columns (ID, Date and Hours) which repeat for each week. I am now using the query I put into my original post to consolidate those.

Answer (score 0):

While it's technically feasible to do this purely in VBA, you should reconsider the union SQL query. The copy and paste code won't look too pretty, but it'd be much easier and faster than building, testing, and debugging that VBA.

(You can even get creative with basic Excel functions to write parts of the union query for you. Just paste your field names into column A and add something like `="["+A1+"],"` to column B)

```
Select [Col1] as "Col1",[Col2] as "Col2",[Col3] as "MyCol3" from [MyTable]
union
Select [Col4],[Col5],[Col6] from [MyTable]
union
Select [Col7],[Col8],[Col9] from [MyTable]
...
```

#### Edit: A better approach

This is to follow up from my comment below.  I'll assume your data is something like this (the first line is the column names):

```
GrpA_Employee GrpA_Email    GrpA_Phone GrpB_Employee GrpB_Email GrpB_Phone 
Abe           Abe@GrpA.Com  111-1111   Bart          Bart@GrpB.com 222-22222
```

In this case, every 'group' gets their own set of 3 columns.  This is cumbersome, difficult to navigate, and as you just discovered, hard to work with for summary purposes.

Try this approach instead:

```
GroupName  Employee  Email         Phone
A          Abe       Abe@GrpA.com  111-1111
B          Bart      Bart@GrpB.com 222-2222
```

This is much easier to work with and you won't have to worry about running out of columns (if you worry about running out of rows, then Excel isn't the best choice).  If your users don't like it because they all want their own columns, then just add some filters at the top so they can filter to their group of choice.

Now, from Access, just link to this 1 table of 4 columns and you're done.  No VBA needed, just a less cumbersome approach to storing data.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, problem is I have something like 240 columns now, and growing monthly.

I have the below code which I think will do the trick, still working on it and I'm sure its not the best way to do it:

Comment: Try editing your original post and dropping the code in there instead.

Comment: I have to agree with @AlexandreP.Levasseur on this one. I don't know why you're storing this data this way, but I think the real problem lies in your Excel data collection method. Perhaps 1 set of 4 columns: 3 for the data you already collect and a 4th column to denote whatever makes the current columns different?

Comment: @user2356011 RE: "I have something like 240 columns now, and growing monthly" - Be aware that in Access a table or query can have no more than 255 columns, so you may want to re-work your approach before you hit that wall.

Comment: Even if there was no such wall, this is an absolutely horrible way to work with databases. This is a case of changing the approach, not finding a technical solution that will make it work.

Comment: Hi @user2356011, I updated my answer with another solution. Would that work for you?

Comment: Hi everyone. Unfortunately this is not my data, I'm simply expected to work with it. Originally the data comes in as a cross tab spreadsheet (pivot table without the detail). I cannot obtain the detail which would have everything stacked normally as would be preferred, I ended up using an excel macro to get to the three column per data set setup which i can at least work with.

There should be a maximum, 52 weeks per year x 3 sets per week x 3 years for maximum historical reporting = 468 columns in total. Worst case I will have to run my process on the data in two chunks to process it all.